# Is there a way to shorten if statements with arc4random_uniform( ) inside them?

Tags: swift, if-statement, ibaction, arc4random

I am having some trouble with some if-statements. I am trying to figure out how to shorten if-statements with `arc4random_uniform` inside them. Here is my code:

func firstCustomNumberRange(sender : AnyObject){

```
    if (firstCustomNumberRangeLabel == 1 )
    {
        var randomNumber = 1
    }


    if (firstCustomNumberRangeLabel == 2 )
    {
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform( 2) + 1
    }


    if (firstCustomNumberRangeLabel == 3 )
    {
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform( 3) + 1
    }


    if (firstCustomNumberRangeLabel == 4 )
    {
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform( 4) + 1
    }
     ...}
```

(I repeated the pattern up to 20). This was a very time consuming process and it took me about 30 minutes just to write these simple if-statements.

Is it possible to shorten if statements with custom `arc4random_uniform( )` inside them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the value of `firstCustomNumberRangeLabel` to `arc4random_uniform()` directly:

```
func firstCustomNumberRange(sender : AnyObject){
    if let numberRange = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(firstCustomNumberRangeLabel.text!) {
        let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numberRange.unsignedIntegerValue)) + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you say `var randomNumber: Double`. I just want to know for future reference.

Comment: Oh, I'm not familiar with the `arc4random_uniform` function, so I was just guessing at its return type. It should set the type of `randomNumber` to whatever `arc4random_uniform` returns - I suppose probably actually an `Int`?

Comment: There is an error saying: 'UILabel' not convertible to a 'UInt32' on the 6th line

Comment: Ah, OK. You will need to use a `NSNumberFormatter` to convert your label (text, I assume?) to a `UInt32`.

Comment: See my edit. If have other problems you may need to re-word your question or ask a new one.